# Coprime indices implies surjectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm currently stuck on the following problem, and could really use a hint.

> Let $H_1, \dotsc, H_n$ be normal subgroups of $G$, and $\varphi : G \to G / H_1 \times \dotsb \times G / H_n$ be defined by $\varphi(g) = (gH_1, \dotsc, gH_n)$.  If each $H_i$ has finite index in $G$, and $\gcd(|G / H_i|, |G / H_j|) = 1$ for all $i \neq j$, then $\varphi$ is surjective.

I hate brining nothing to the table, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to begin.  There aren't any tools that I know to show directly that a function is surjective besides choosing an element of the codomain and showing that it has a preimage in the domain.  To me, this doesn't seem like a feasible approach here, so my gut is telling me that a contradiction might be the way to go.  However, I don't see how to get one.

I've even tried looking at an abstract mock example consisting of just two normal subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of indices $3$ and $4$, respectively, to see how the pieces might fit together.  For instance, say $G / H_1 = \{ H_1, g_1H_1, g_2H_1 \}$ and $G / H_2 = \{ H_2, \gamma_1H_2, \gamma_2H_2, \gamma_3H_2 \}$.  This didn't help.  I'm just looking for suggestions or hints if at all possible.

EDIT:  I'm thinking now that I should be looking at $|\varphi(G)|$, since it divides $\prod_i |G / H_i|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $\ker \varphi = \bigcap H_i$. It has finite index $I = [G : \ker\varphi]$ in $G$. If you look at the composition of $\varphi$ with the projection onto the $i$-th factor, you will note that that is surjective, whence

$$[G : H_i] \mid I.$$

Since all the $[G:H_i]$ are coprime, it follows that

$$\prod_i [G : H_i] \mid I,$$

whence $\lvert \operatorname{im}\varphi\rvert \geqslant \prod_i [G:H_i]$. But of course that is the order of the codomain, hence $\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I'm having trouble verifying $[G : H_i] \mid I$. Say $\pi_i$ is the projection onto the $i^{th}$ factor $G / H_i$. I see how $\pi_i \circ \varphi$ is surjective.  Now $|G / H_i| = |im(\pi_i \circ \varphi)| = |G / \ker(\pi_i \circ \varphi)|$ divides $|G / \ker(\varphi)|$?  I'm sorry but I don't see why.

Comment: You have $$G/H_j \cong \frac{G/\ker\varphi}{H_j/\ker\varphi}$$ for every $j$, so $[G : \ker\varphi] = [G : H_j]\cdot [H_j : \ker\varphi]$.